# Size of dictionary is 0

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

Is there some special way how get dictionary size?

I am adding two elements into it. Printing it using STON returns:

```
{'1':DBDiceBag{#dice:OrderedCollection[]},'2':DBDiceBag{#dice:OrderedCollection[]}}
```

which is correct. However using

```
r myDIctionary size
```

returns always 0.
Is there some workaround or how to do it?

Comment: What do you get when you evaluate `r myDictionary`? If `myDictionary` is the getter of a dictionary held in an instance var of `r`, check that you haven't forgotten the return operator `^`; otherwise, `myDictionary` will answer with `r` and, most likely, `r size = 0`.

Answer (score 2):

**One of the most frequent mistakes in Smalltalk** is to forget the **explicit** result token `^` in a method.

Based on this question, this would be the most plausible explanation, so let me elaborate.

Assume you have a class `R` that defines an instance variable `dictionary`, which happens to hold some instance of `Dictionary`. The getter of such an ivar would simply look like:

```smalltalk
myDictionary
  ^dictionary
```

However, if we forgot the return token, our code would read

```smalltalk
myDictionary
  dictionary
```

without any **explicit** return. Therefore, the sender of this message would get the **implicit** return instead, which is `self` (meaning the receiver of `myDictionary`). In other words, this would be equivalent to

```smalltalk
myDictionary
  dictionary.
  ^self                  "<- no need to make this explicit here"
```

and the sender would get the instance of `R` rather than its `dictionary` ivar. Thus, the expression

```smalltalk
r myDictionary size
```

would be sending `#size` to the result of `r myDictionary`, which after our mistake is nothing but `r`. In other words, it would be equivalent to

```smalltalk
r size
```

And since in Smalltalk every `Object` responds to `#size`, this would raise no `MessageNotUnderstood` exception and the mistake would remain unnoticed.

Now, why `r size` is `0`? Because, by default, non-arrayed objects respond to `#size` with zero, indicating that they have `0` indexed slots. You can change this default behavior and override `#size` with something else, but if you don't this is what will happen.